# I want to link my Firebase account to GitHub

Tags: github, firebase

I want to link firebase Github, but I get "Your account is not linked to GitHub. Please sign in with your email and password."

Where and how to I link the accounts?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't signup for a Firebase account with Github. Do you mean you want to enable Github authentication for users of your Firebase app? If so, see https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/github.html

Comment: Not a programming issue. Ask Firebase or GitHub Support instead.

Comment: Firebase support would be appropriate. Email to support at firebase and we'll fix you up.

Comment: It's not a GitHub or FB auth issue. The link to login to Firebase using GitHub is right on the firebase login page. It's not clear how to actually link them though. Usually that sort of functionality is in a user profile page or something of the sort.

Comment: Useful discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/q8kDjNDMj8A

Comment: @Kato I'll try, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging in to firebase using Github is a feature that has been discontinued, but firebase still asks as a feature to users that were grandfathered in.

Comment: Their website begs to differ. "Sign In or {GitHub Icon}" there now, but it's also not clear how to link one's account to GitHub.

Comment: It was the button that made me ask the question in the first place. The button works, but only for users who already created an account via github Oauth.   If you don't have an account already, then that button doesn't work. They keep the button for the old users.